# Anonymous actors in activity streams

Tags: python, django, django-notification, activity-streams

I'm working with a system that has a number of notifications around the creation of items within groups and am trying to model anonymous actors in notifications.

Consider the contrived example:

> A `Book` belongs to a `Library`, and I am a user of the library interested in books in a particular topic. The library keeps me informed of when books of a certain topic are checked out, but for security reasons doesn't let me know who checked it out.

The activity stream for this would be:

> A patron (`actor`) checked out (`verb`) the book "Learning Python, 5th Edition" (`object`) in the subject "Computer books" (`target`).

The problem here is that "A patron" isn't an entity in my database, particularly in my case, Django-notifications *requires* an actor, and that that actor be a instance of a model. But in this case there is no "actor" as such.

Is there a better way to write this activity stream? Is there a way to write it that doesn't involve putting a fake actor into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You decide how to represent the notifications. 
You could save these type of notifications like that:

> "Learning Python, 5th Edition" (actor) was checked out (verb) by a patron in the subject "Computer books" (target)

If you see closer - in that way, your patron becomes an `action object` if it was a real entity. But saving it in this way it doesn't mean that it should be represented in that way. You could render this in the template as you want.

One note from the [docs](http://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/actions.html) where if you replace `query` with `render` you will get my point:

> Actions are generated in a manner independent of how you wish to query them so they can be queried later to generate different streams based on all possible associations.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this, but can you find anything from the activitystrea.ms documentation that supports it? If not it seems like a good answer, I just didn't want to be non-conformant.

Comment: Can't give an answer to that, but I would be interested to know the answer to this question. I can only say from my experience that i faced the same problem a month  and solving it in that way didn't cause me any additional problems. There were event grouping of the notifications like the ones in facebook and it actually ended pretty well.